# Return unique rows of records for each user

Tags: mysql

I have a table that tracks different qualifications for students. The qualifications are renewed periodically, so many students have multiple records for the same qualification.

I'm trying to return just the most recent record of each qualification for each student, without the duplicates.

So far I have this, but I'm stuck on what I need to do to remove the duplicate `type_scrn` and just return the most recent records.

```
SELECT scrn.*
FROM cert_scrn scrn
WHERE scrn.id_scrn = (SELECT scrn2.id_scrn 
    FROM cert_scrn scrn2
    WHERE scrn.id_scrn = scrn2.id_scrn
    AND ( scrn2.type_scrn = 1
        OR scrn2.type_scrn = 11
        OR scrn2.type_scrn = 12
        OR scrn2.type_scrn = 13 )
    ORDER BY scrn2.expiredate_scrn DESC  LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY  scrn.idstu_scrn
```

This returns:

```
id_scrn | idstu_scrn | type_scrn | expiredate_scrn
-------------------------------------------------
15      | 58         | 1         | 2010-01-26
1539    | 58         | 1         | 2015-06-21
5790    | 58         | 11        | 2016-02-20
5791    | 58         | 12        | 2016-02-20
5792    | 58         | 13        | 2016-02-20
```

What I need returned:

```
id_scrn | idstu_scrn | type_scrn | expiredate_scrn
---------------------------------------------------
1539    | 58         | 1         | 2015-06-21
5790    | 58         | 11        | 2016-02-20
5791    | 58         | 12        | 2016-02-20
5792    | 58         | 13        | 2016-02-20
```

Comment: Do you have any date, timestamp column? Is id_scrn a primary key column?

Comment: Is expiredate_scrn a field in the cert_scrn table?

Comment: I have a date column (YYYY-MM-DD format), I left it off for simplicity since `id_scrn` is a primary key and I'll always want the most recently added record, but I'll edit the dates in if that's an easier method.

Comment: My suggestion is to use group by clause.

Comment: Try like this:
SELECT scrn.*
FROM cert_scrn scrn
WHERE scrn.id_scrn = (SELECT MAX(scrn2.id_scrn) AS  
    FROM cert_scrn scrn2
    WHERE scrn.id_scrn = scrn2.id_scrn
    AND scrn2.type_scrn IN (1,11,12,13 ) 
 GROUP BY scrn2.idstu_scrn,scrn2.type_scrn 
    ORDER BY scrn2.expiredate_scrn DESC  LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY  scrn.idstu_scrn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to a subquery which finds the max date for each `idstu_scn`, `type_scrn` group.

So your query to get the `max(date)` would be:

```
select idstu_scrn, type_scrn, max(expiredate_scrn) mdate
  from cert_scrn
  group by idstu_scrn, type_scrn
```

Which we then just need to join back to the `cert_scrn` table again, to find the rest of the details to go along with it.

```
select scrn.*
  from cert_scrn scrn
    inner join (
      select idstu_scrn, type_scrn, max(expiredate_scrn) mdate
        from cert_scrn
        group by idstu_scrn, type_scrn ) q
      on scrn.idstu_scrn = q.idstu_scrn and scrn.type_scrn = q.type_scrn and scrn.expiredate_scrn = q.mdate
  where scrn.type_scrn = 1
    or scrn.type_scrn = 11
    or scrn.type_scrn = 12
    or scrn.type_scrn = 13
```

[demo fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee55f/5)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one based on Primary Key, appears working fine for this scenario :

```
SELECT * FROM cert_scrn WHERE id_scrn IN 
(SELECT MAX(id_scrn) FROM cert_scrn GROUP BY idstu_scrn, type_scrn);
```

Comment: @Zoe - Would you be able to check this?

Comment: It appears to work, thank you, but any idea why it takes almost a minute to execute (on a table of about 5k rows), while the other solution averages 0.2 sec?